# USB drive not showing in Gparted

Tags: gparted, usb-drive

I have a USB drive which is formatted for the fat 32 file system (I formatted it on a Windows computer).  Now I want to perform some operations on it using gparted.  However, the USB drive is not showing when I click the drop down in the upper right.
[image]

Here is the output when I run dmesg -wH:
[image]

Comment: Formatting of the drive should not matter. Please add the output of `lsblk` to your question.

Comment: Did your USB drive ever got recognized? Try `lsusb`, or even tail the kernel log `dmesg` for more info.

Comment: @Rovo I don't understand.  gparted is a GUI and I see no such menu option.  Sorry that I am not very knowledgeable.

Comment: @KongChunHo Yes, I see the USB drive name showing up on the desktop.  Are these commands for parted?

Comment: @whitelightning `lsusb` shows what *USB Devices* that are currently connected to the computer. If the device is being recognized, post the kernel log by editing this post. To obtain the kernel log, unplug the USB drive, run `dmesg -wH`, plug-in the USB drive, and post the output between. Also, as mentioned by @RoVo, please post the output of `lsblk`.

Comment: @whitelightning Please use a terminal to run these command, forget about gparted at this time first.

Comment: @KongChunHo thank you.  I just now added that.

Comment: @whitelightning It seems that there is a 16GB USB Drive at `/dev/sdb`, are you sure gparted top-right drop down menu have no `/dev/sdb`?

Comment: @KongChunHo Hmm.. I do see it there now.  Very strange that this is the first that I am noticing.  I think I did change which USB port it was plugged into (I just so happened to move it for another reason, not for troubleshooting purposes).  At the very least, it was good to learn about the dmesg command.  This forum is great, and I have a lot of reading and learning to do :)